# The session not getting cleared in logout

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am developing a web application using `jsp` and `servlet`. In my application I have a logout section, in which I am using the following code:

```
public class logout extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpSession ss = rq.getSession(false);
            if (ss.getAttribute("uid") == null) {
                rs.sendRedirect("/");
            }

            rs.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            rs.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            rs.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            HttpSession session = rq.getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("uid", null);
            session.invalidate();
            rs.sendRedirect("/");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            //  rs.sendRedirect("/");
            RequestDispatcher dd = rq.getRequestDispatcher("/");
            dd.forward(rq, rs);
        }

    }
}
```

In browser if we use continuously and suppose a week **without clearing history**, then if we login and click logout, it is getting logout redirected to home page but the session still persists. **The session not getting cleared in logout**.

What is this problem happening? Is there any more changes needed in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the problem is,but some suggestions.

1. Don't need to create two HttpSession objects (ss and session), try using only one.
2. Try removing the "uid" attribute ,rather than making it null.
3. Try checking the HttpSession is null or not before invoking the invalidate() method on it.

So the final code will be,

```
public class logout extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            rs.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            rs.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            rs.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            HttpSession ss = rq.getSession(false);
            if (ss.getAttribute("uid") == null) {
                rs.sendRedirect("/");
            }

            ss.removeAttribute("uid");
            if (ss != null) {
                ss.invalidate();
            }
            rs.sendRedirect("/");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            //  rs.sendRedirect("/");
            RequestDispatcher dd = rq.getRequestDispatcher("/");
            dd.forward(rq, rs);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I feel some problem in this line HttpSession ss = rq.getSession(false); As mentioned above code!!

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: NOPE!!  I did not get any

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not user proper session management into your application.
I suggest to use custom filter for to prevent browser catche for each page  .

```
 rs.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
 rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 rs.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 rs.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

After going this you need to check session is valid for each request via filter or check session valid on each page (view) if session is invalid then redirect to index page.

and make some correction into Logout controller.

```
 public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpSession session = rq.getSession(false);
        session.removeAttribute("uid");
        session.invalidate();
        rs.sendRedirect("/");
    } catch (Exception exp) {
       RequestDispatcher dd = rq.getRequestDispatcher("/");
        dd.forward(rq, rs);
    }

}
```